# How can I move a picture from the application storage to the camera roll (Photo Folder) on an IPad via ActionScript?

Tags: ipad, actionscript, move, image

I'm currently programming an Art App for IPad. The user should be able to save the picture he created into the Photo Folder of his IPad. I tried to do this with the CameraRoll API, but sadly it only saves the picture as .jpg, which basically destroys it, due to the compression.

So I tried to save the picture as .png file in the storage of the app itself and this seems to work. But I have no idea how I move the picture to the Photos Folder now.

Here is my code:

```
var flattenPicture:BitmapData = canvas.flatForSave();
var imgByteArray:ByteArray = pngenc.encode(flattenPicture);

var outputFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("Bild.png");
var outputStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
outputStream.open(outputFile, FileMode.WRITE);
outputStream.writeBytes(imgByteArray, 0, imgByteArray.length);
outputStream.close();

var loadFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("Bild.png");
var fotoFile:File = new File();
fotoFile.nativePath = "/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/Bild.png";
loadFile.moveTo(fotoFile,true);
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

I would really appreciate any kind of help! Thank you very much in advance!